# How do I move a byte into a specific location in a data register?

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000, easy68k

I want to move 4 bytes, **$B1,B2,B3,B4**, one at a time, into data register **D1**.

The value I want in D1 is **$B1B2B3B4**.

Which instruction(s) will help me do this?

Comment: Usually a combination of left shift and bitwise or

Comment: Either that, or store the bytes sequentially in memory and then MOVE.L them into D1.

Comment: The code presented will result in D1 containing $B4B3B2B1 and not $B1B2B3B4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using LSL (Thank you, Chris Stratton), and SWAP:

```
MOVE.B      #$B1,D0
LSL         #8,D0
MOVE.B      #$B2,D0
SWAP        D0
MOVE.B      #$B3,D0
LSL         #8,D0
MOVE.B      #$B4,D0
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in using `SWAP` to do this, just combine moves, ors and shifts:

```
MOVE.B  #$B1, D0  ; D0 now $xxxxxxB1
LSL.L   #8, D0    ; $xxxxB100
ORI.B   #$B2, D0  ; $xxxxB1B2
LSL.L   #8, D0    ; $xxB1B200
ORI.B   #$B3, D0  ; $xxB1B2B3
LSL.L   #8, D0    ; $B1B2B300
ORI.B   #$B4, D0  ; $B1B2B3B4
```

Maybe it's not shorter or faster, but at least I think it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can just be direct about it:

```
MOVE.L #$B1B2B3B4,D0
```

(shrug)

There are clever ways to do what you want if you need to save memory or run very fast.